# Why does strlen() not represent the actual length of my string?

Tags: c

basically I have a string composed of multiple words like this: `"Hello world test"`.
Either if I try to print it with a structure like this

```
printf("%s", string);
```

or like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); ++i) {
    printf("%c", string[i];
}
```

I always get this as an output: `Hello world` and I get a strlen of 11 instead of 16 too.

If I try to print out the same exact string with an int counter that previously counts the single chars in the string

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; ++i) {
    printf("%c", string[i];
}
```

I actually get the correct output `Hello world test`, which leads be to believe that the elements are correctly assigned in the string but for some reason %s and strlen just ignores the ones after the last space.

Why would that happen? What is going on? How can I fix this?

EDIT:

Actual code as requested:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef int BOOL;
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0


int main() {
    char sentence[64] = " ", reversal[64] = " ", reversal_copy[64] = " ";
    int index = 0, counter = 0;
    BOOL reset = TRUE, last_cycle = FALSE;

    printf("Enter a sentence: ");
    for (int i = 0; sentence[strlen(sentence) - 1] != '\n'; i++) {
        scanf("%c", &sentence[i]);
    }

    /* Copies the input in a string reversing it */
    for (int h = strlen(sentence) - 2, k = 0; h >= 0; h--, k++) {
        reversal[k] = sentence[h];
    }

    /* Detects the first character of a word and the last character of the same word before a space,
    switching the first char with the last, the second with the pre-last and so on*/
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(reversal); i++) {
        if (reset == TRUE) {
            index = i;
            reset = FALSE;
        }
        if (i == strlen(reversal) - 1) {
            last_cycle = TRUE;
            counter++;
        }
        if (reversal[i] != ' ') {
            counter++;
            if (last_cycle == TRUE) {
                goto reversing;
            }
        }
        else {
        reversing:
            for (int h = index, z = counter; h < counter; h++, z--) {
                reversal_copy[h] = reversal[z - 1];
                reversal_copy[z - 1] = reversal[h];
            }
            if (last_cycle == FALSE) {
                reversal_copy[i] = ' ';
            }
            reset = TRUE;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    printf("%lu ", strlen(reversal_copy));
    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
        printf("%c", reversal_copy[i]);
    }
    printf("%s\n\n", reversal_copy);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does the value `"Hello world test"` get into `string`? [mcve]?

Comment: please show your actual code

Comment: @Swordfish it gets assigned character by character from a function

Comment: @FoxyIT that code is broken, it has inserted a '\0' into the string

Comment: @pm100 I don't get how that could happen to be honest ahah

Comment: somewhere in there you have copied the trailing '0' after the word 'test' to the beginning of the word 'tset'. ie you have an out by 1 error in a loop

Comment: *`typedef int BOOL;`* *~>* `#include <stdbool.h>` for gods sake. What is that program supposed to do (I am too lazy to try to figure it out from the code)? The correct format specifier for `size_t` the result of `strlen()` is `"%zu"` btw.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; sentence[strlen(sentence) - 1] != '\n'; i++) {` is very odd.  you should test `sentence[i]` inside the loop, after assigning it.

Comment: if you dont believe it then change your test printf(%c) loop to a printf(%x) loop. You will see a 0 in there (rather than a 20 )

Comment: @AShelly already tested that bit ahah works fine

Comment: @Swordfish sorry ahah that's how my book has explained booleans so far ahah anyways the program takes a string inputted by the user like "the sky is blue" and prints out "blue is sky the"

Comment: 'I don't get how that could happen to be honest' - well either you have a bug in that code, or you have discovered a previously unknown bug in strlen , your CPU or compiler. Which do you think it is?

Comment: @pm100 dude I didn't intend that my code was perfect and I'm some sort of genius, I just meant that I genuinely couldn't find where the mistake was because I'm still a beginner and if I could get some help...

Comment: @pm100 yes I had said it at the beginning before I actually got all the answers, thanks. No need to be so rude

Comment: the first thing to note here is that you did not 0 terminate the string called 'reversal'. YOu need to add reversal[k] = '\0' after the loop

Comment: _Side note:_ `strlen` has non-zero execution cost, so try to avoid it in a `for` loop condition clause. Better: `int revlen = strlen(reverse); for (int i = 0; i < revlen; i++) {` and likewise replacing it within that loop. Otherwise, if your length was N, you'll do `N*N` scans of the chars in the string.

Comment: @FoxyIT `strtok` is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running your program with the input "A" as an example - see that even a single word exhibits the problem.

Something is going wrong when you reverse the last word.  You are putting the trailing `'\0'` in front of it.  It probably has to do with the special casing and the `goto` around the `last_cycle` logic, which is very hard to follow.

I think it's probably related to the fact that you have two `counter++`s in that code path.

Consider using some functions to make the code cleaner:

```
len = strlen(reversal);
for (start=0; start<len; start++) {
   end = find_space_or_null(reversal, start);
   if (end > start) {
    reverse_chars(reversal, start, end-1);
    start = end;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if `strlen()` returns 11 then you have a `\0` char after the world "world".

`strlen` and `printf` both determine "what is a string" by using the 0 terminator, so no surprise that they behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

While this is difficult to answer without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I will explain the most likely reason for the behavior you're observing.

Both `printf` with the `%s` format specifier and `strlen` give you the length of the *null-terminated string* pointed to by the relevant argument. If they are printing/reporting a length of 11, but iterating through the entire char array with a hard-coded value of 16 gives you the output "hello world test", then the character after world is clearly the null character, '\0'.

Answer (score 0):

> the program takes a string inputted by the user like "the sky is blue" and prints out "blue is sky the"

That's a perfect job for [`strtok()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok):

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAX_LINE = 120 };

int main()
{
    char buffer[MAX_LINE];
    fgets(buffer, MAX_LINE, stdin);

    size_t length = strlen(buffer);
    if (length && buffer[length - 1] == '\n')  // get rid of the newline
        buffer[--length] = '\0';

    char *tokens[MAX_LINE] = { 0 };  // there can't be more than 60 tokens, but hey
    if ((tokens[0] = strtok(buffer, " ")) == NULL)  // no tokens? nothing to do.
        return 0;

    size_t i = 1;
    for (; tokens[i - 1] && i < sizeof(tokens); ++i)
        tokens[i] = strtok(NULL, " ");  // tokenize the buffer

    --i;  // the very last was NULL anyway.
    while (--i)  // print it reverse
        printf("%s ", tokens[i]);
    puts(buffer);
}
```

#### Sample Output:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
dog lazy the over jumps fox brown quick The
```